# How can I get EntityManager.getReference when the id(primay keys) are more than 1?

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager, zk

guys, I desperately to know how can I use EntityManager.getReference with more than 1 primary keys because I always get error when I want to update data,
the error message kind of like :

> [EL Fine]: sql: Connection(1713950866)--SELECT Category, SubCategory, Code, CreatedBy, CreatedDateTime, IsActive, Remarks, UpdatedBy, UpdatedDateTime, Value FROM master.sysParameter WHERE (((Category = ?) AND (SubCategory = ?)) AND (Code = ?))
>       **bind => [acm, acm, acm]**
>   javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Could not find entity for id: acm
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.getReference(EntityManagerImpl.java:1398)

which in my codes I want to define 3 variables but I only get 1 (acm).
here's the examples of my codes :

```
    public boolean updateSysParameter(MasterSysParameterEntity masterSysParameter) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    boolean retVal = false;
    try{
        MasterSysParameterEntity updateSysParameter;
        em = getEntityManagerFactory();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        System.out.println("masterSysParameter.getCategory() => " +masterSysParameter.getCategory());

        updateSysParameter = em.getReference(MasterSysParameterEntity.class, masterSysParameter.getCategory());
        updateSysParameter = em.getReference(MasterSysParameterEntity.class, masterSysParameter.getSubCategory());
        updateSysParameter = em.getReference(MasterSysParameterEntity.class, masterSysParameter.getCode());

        updateSysParameter = em.merge(masterSysParameter);

        em.getTransaction().commit();
        retVal = true;
    }catch (Exception e) {
        if(em != null && null != em.getTransaction())
            em.getTransaction().rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (em != null) {
            em.close();
        }
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Thanks a lot for any advice and help, it really means a lot

Comment: if there is more than one "Id" field then you should pass in an object of the type of "IdClass" for that class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have multiple `@Id` fields in an entity then you define an `@IdClass` [on the entity for the composite id](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_2/jpa/application_identity.html#PrimaryKey_Example_-_Multiple_Field). And so you call `em.getReference` passing in the second argument as an instance of the "IdClass".

```
MyIdClass myId = new MyIdClass(...); // Pass in whatever args your IdClass needs
MyEntity ent = em.getReference(MyEntity.class, myId);
```

Comment: dude, i still don't get how using em.getReference with this IdClass, do you have an example? I already define IdClass and create class like the link you shared. and then I got stuck implement this em.getReference

Comment: No idea who "dude" is, nor why you need an "example" (the link in the post shows you how to create an IdClass ... but then you MUST have done that to get this far - but you STILL don't quote your Entity class in your "question"). Updated post stating the getReference call.